# Kotlin sublist from element

Tags: kotlin, sublist

I have a list and element:

```
val element = "b"
val myList = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

And I would like to have a sublist starting after a given element.

So the result would be:

```
"c", "d"
```

I wonder if there is a built-in function to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 val newArray = myList.takeLastWhile { it != element }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are generally several ways to achive this. 
Kasima's answer is very good, but you can also try it this way:

```
val sublist = myList.subList(myList.indexOf(element) + 1, myList.size)
```